# Android : Updating UI components from async class

Tags: java, android

I have UI component where I have table which consist of ImageViews, Now I want to set the image from URL.

Now when I try to call asynchronously the other class where the image is set to UI it gives me error that UI can be updated only by UI thread. I want to load the UI and load images when they are available.

Here is my code :

```
Calling function...
    new AsyncImageLoader(context,imgviewArray).execute();

//    Called class..
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            int i = 0;

            try{
                db=new MyDB(mainact_instance);
                System.out.println("Inside doInBackground");

                if(isNetworkAvailable())
                {
                    System.out.println("Network connected");
                    System.out.println("Fetching from network-Images");
                    Movie[] movies = db.selectRecords();
                    for(Movie mv : movies)
                    {
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(IMAGE_URL+mv.getId()+".jpg");
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            images[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);
                            i++;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }

                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("Network not connected..fetching max id row");
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
            //db.close();       
        }
```

Please tell me how I can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move your UI thread related code to `onPostExecute` || `onProgressUpdate`

for example:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

 // after finishing fetching your image from URL, update the ImageView here
 images[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

I can see you are downloading multiple images inside the `AsyncTask` then you can use `PublishProgress` you need to update your AsyncTask definition to allow passing Bitmaps to publishProgress method as follow:

```
AsyncTask<whatever..., Bitmaps, whatever...>()
```

Then

```
publishProgress(yourBitmapObject);

protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap[] values) {
  images[i].setImageBitmap(values[0]);
};
```